# Figure causes chapter to start on middle of the page

Tags: floats, chapters

I have a chapter, it has some text and then a figure is included using this code

```
\chapter{Mock-ups And Data Slicing Functionality}
 First text line.

 Second text line \ref{img: applicationPlot}.
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/applicationPlot.pdf}
 \caption{OpenDiabetesVault: Graph}
 \label{img: applicationPlot}
 \end{figure}
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/PlotLegend.png}
 \caption{OpenDiabetesVault: Graph Legends \cite{ODV}}
 \label{img: PlotLegend}
 \end{figure}
```

This causes the chapter to start from not the default position but it is floating somewhere in the 2nd quarter of the page in PDF. Removing it takes the chapter back to normal position. Find the attached image [image]

The included packages are following

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
```

Comment: that would not be the default behaviour, and (again) you have shown no code  using `[H]` option (presumably from the `float` package?) by design introduces large spaces, but it would not normally affect the space above a chapter head which is a fixed space in most document classes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited the questions to show the packages, I have not changed anything other than the defaults.

Comment: none of the packages that you show defines a `\chapter` command , so you have still not shown either the definitiion or the use of the command that you are asking about, that makes it hard to help you

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am having issues locating the defination of chapter command in my document. I will update the post once I locate where it is. I am using a university-provided template, so don't where is what at the moment. First-time latex user.

Comment: really the example you post should be a complete small document that can be used to debug the problem  you can use `example-image` as the image and random text as any text as they are not that relevant to your question, which is about the so far unseen definition and use of `\chapter`.

Comment: The template you are using is probably causing this.